# Ls command KornShell

Tags: shell, unix, grep, ksh

I have a folder called `.dir`. When I type `ls -al | grep .dir` it finds it and shows me the result, but when I type `ls -al | grep *dir` or (`*i*`, `*d*`) it shows nothing. I can not understand why it does not find any matches.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you do `grep *dir` two things can happen:

1. If there are any non-hidden file ending in `dir` say for example (`foodir` and `bardir`), the command will be expanded to `grep foodir bardir` and it will not do what you expect. Moreover the behavior will differ depending on there was just one file or more than one...
2. There are no non-hidden files ending in `dir`, then `*dir` is not expanded but used as the regular expression in the grep call. But the asterisk in grep is used to repeat the last match any number of times, and since there is no previous character it stands for itself. Conclusion: grep is looking for "*dir", literally.

For the first problem just use quotes. For the second use `.*dir` (`.` stands for any character):

```
ls -la | grep ".*dir"
```

Or if you want to see just your directory:

```
ls -la | grep "\.dir"
```

Note that if you do not escape the `.` with a `\` it show also files such as `adir`, `_dir`...

Answer (score 0):

- Unquoted asterisks are [expanded](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/073) before being passed to `grep`. That means if your directory is empty except for the `.dir` directory, the string passed to `grep` depends on the status of the `dotglob` and `nullglob` settings (in Bash; I don't know their Korn shell equivalents):

  ```
  $ cd -- "$(mktemp -d)"
  $ mkdir .dir
  $ shopt -u dotglob nullglob
  $ echo *dir
  *dir
  $ shopt -s nullglob
  $ echo *dir

  $ shopt -s dotglob
  $ echo *dir
  .dir
  ```
- `grep` works with [regular expressions](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/RegularExpression), not [globs](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob). `*` is a valid glob, but not a valid regular expression without anything before it.